# Docker-compose v2 expose port to machine

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I used to use v1 of docker-compose to run a set of services and then use the dev serve of Django to connect to them. I used to connect to the services (such as a db) with the `<machine_ip>:<port>` (smt like `192.168.99.100:5432` for postgres)

Now, i just installed docker for mac, and v1 is not working. I moved to version 2 but Django complains that there's no service listening to the port `5432`. As far as I understood it's a problem of the `network`, but I can't get my head around on how to configure it. In theory a default network is created for all the services within the compose, which is fine in general but not for my case. I use compose to spin up a set of services to connect to my local execution of django.

this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes_from:
      - data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  es:
    image: elasticsearch:2.3
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "48429:48429"
  data:
    # use this that is already downloaded
    # links just to keep the db
    image: alpine:3.3
    command: echo 'Data Container for PostgreSQL'
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

and in my django conf

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '192.168.99.100',  # 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'  # '6543'
    },
}
```

where `192.168.99.100` is the `docker-machine ip`

the result is

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "192.168.99.100" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

any help on how I can expose all these ports to the machine ip?

Comment: you should try to replace 192.168.99.100 in DATABASES with "data"

Comment: Note that data containers are largely gone away in favor of named volumes. For a connectivity problem like this, work from the container back out to find out where the connection is failing. Make sure the port is open on the container and service is listening, try it from the Docker host VM, and then try it from your laptop. Newer versions of Docker for Mac/Win are doing more to hide the VM, so if you're on the beta, you may also try the port on localhost.

Comment: On linux, `sudo netstat -luntp` is useful for seeing what ports are currently listening and by what process (do not skip the sudo if you want to see processes).

Comment: i deleted and recreated the machine and now it's working. It's probably a migration problem from the old docker to the brand new docker-mac

Comment: @BMitch what do you mean with " 
Note that data containers are largely gone away in favor of named volumes. " ?

Comment: Named volumes let you manage them with `docker volume ...` and persist independent of containers. The code for doing a `--volumes-from` still exists, but I wouldn't use it for anything new.

Comment: can you point to me the documentation about this?

Comment: look at my answer. I set up the named volume for you too... https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create

Answer (score 1):

Try to use dockers internal network features to let the container talk to each other.

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - datavolume_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  es:
    image: elasticsearch:2.3
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "48429:48429"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
# Named volume
volumes:
  datavolume_postgres: {}

#You dont need to specify the default network
```

and in your `django.conf`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',  # 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'  # '6543'
    },
}
```

I don't know on what `es` depends bu i hope you get the Point

FYI [depends_on reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/depends-on)

Comment: I was trying to use this conf for named volumes, but it does not work. how should i use named volumes in the correct way? (`volume must be a mapping, not an array`)

Comment: Oh crap! Sorry for that. I edited my post to fix this problem.